# Applying formatting to a specific row in addition to column formatting with xlsxwriter using pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, xlsxwriter

I am formatting all of my columns in an excel file using the xlsxwriter module:

```py
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('abc.xlsx', {'nan_inf_to_errors': True})

cell_format = workbook.add_format({'align' : 'left','border' : 1, "border_color": "black"})
ROI_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0.00','align':'center','border' : 1, "border_color": "black"})

spend_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0','align':'right','border' : 1, "border_color": "black"})

Header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold':True,'align':'center','bg_color':'#FDE9D9','border' : 1, "border_color": "black",})

global_format = workbook.add_format({'bold':True,'align':'center','bg_color':'#DCE6F1','border' : 1, "border_color": "black",})

WS1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
WS1.write_row('B4:N4', np.repeat(None, len(COUNTRY_DATA.columns)), global_format)

for col in COUNTRY_DATA.columns:
    if 'ROI' in col:
        WS1.write_column(first_col + first_row,COUNTRY_DATA\[col\], cell_format = ROI_format)
    if 'SPEND' in col:
        WS1.write_column(first_col + first_row,COUNTRY_DATA\[col\], cell_format = spend_format)

WS1.write_row('B3', colsToWrite, Header_format)
workbook.close()
```

Now when I run this code the formatting applied in row 4 with global_format is getting overwritten by column formatting, running after this (ROI_format or spend_format). **I want to keep both the formatting ** because column format is applied to all the rows and row format is applied to only row 4 which has total data.

Comment: What is `COUNTRY_DATA` in your question? Also, `colsToWrite`, `first_col ` & `first_row` are never initialized anywhere in the code. Try to produce a minimal reproducible example. Refer - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -2):

```
for col, columns in enumerate(COUNTRY_DATA.columns, +2):
        if columns == "ROI":
            WS1.write_column(your_parameters_here)

        elif columns == "SPEND":
            WS1.write_column(your_parameters_here)
```

Comment: What's up with the call to `enumerate()` here? The original code doesn't have that, and it doesn't do anything remotely useful. And why are you calling it with a `start` value of `+2`? Why is `columns` plural? Why `your_parameters_here` instead of a detailed answer?

Comment: This code is not solving my purpose of applying two formatting to a row (row formatting and column formatting), for e.g. I want to add color to a range B4:N4 it is getting overwritten by column formatting which is running after that formatting in for loop.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.